# If $f(u)=0$ implies $f(v)=0$, then $u=kv$

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space and $u,v \in V$. Consider $V^*$, the dual space of $V$. If for every $f \in V^*$ $f(u)=0$ implies $f(v) =0$, then $u=kv$ for some scalar $k$.

Comment: This is false. Let $V = \mathbb{R}$, $u = 1$ and $v = 0$. Then for every $f \in \mathbb{R}^*$, $f(u) = 0 \implies f(v) = 0$, but you can't write $u = kv$ for some scalar $k$.

Comment: Most probably the OP meant that one of the vectors is a scalar multiple of the other one. At least that is the intention, I think, of this exercise...

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\;\{u,\,v\}\;$ is linearly independent, so we can expand this set to a basis $\;\mathcal B\;$ of the whole space $\;V\;$ (this is immediate in case $\;\dim V<\infty\;$ , otherwise we need the axiom of choice). Define $\;\phi: V\to\Bbb F\;,\;\;\Bbb F=\;$ the field over which $\;V\;$ is defined,  by

$$\phi v=1,\,\;\text{and}\;\;\;\phi w=0\;\;\forall\, w\in\mathcal B\,,\;\;w\neq v$$

and expand by linearity to the whole $\;V\;$ . Then clearly $\;\phi\in V^*\;$ and $\;\phi v=0\;$ **but** $\;\phi u\neq0\;$ .

Thus $\;\{u,v\}\;$ is a linearly dependent set and thus one of the vectors is a multiple scalar of the other one. Since it could be that $\;u=0\;$ (why cannot be $\;v=0\;$?), we get $\;u=kv\;$ , for some scalar $\;k\in\Bbb F\;$

Comment: $\phi$ should be defined by $\phi v = 1, \phi w = 0 | w \neq v$ (since you need $\phi u = 0 \wedge \phi v \neq 0$ for a counterexample). Also, **Najib Idrissi** made a good point in a comment: $\nexists k : u = kv$ is not the same as $\{u,v\}$ being linearly independent.

Comment: @Abstraction First, I chose $\;\phi v=0\wedge\phi u\neq0\;$ as counterexample, not $\;\phi u=0\wedge\phi v\neq0\;$ . Of course, it is the same. Second, I never said that it was the same, but if $\;\{u,v\}\;$ is linearly independent then it **cannot be** that $\;u=kv\;$ , which is what I show and thus you have a contradiction, so $\;\{u,v\}\;$ is linearly *dependent* and thus one of the vectors is a scalar multiple of the other one. If you want to be **very** precise you can choose $\;u\;$ a scalar multiple of $\;v\;$ as in the question, but this is unimportant imo. I shall though change it. Th

Comment: I have one question.If I assume cu+dv=0 first and then operate phi on them,then I get c×0+d×0=0,and this relation holds for arbitrary values of c and d.From this can I say that {u,v} is linearly independent?

Comment: sorry that will be linearly dependent..